# Get value from one textbox to another XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, popup

I have created a text box which when focused brings up a popup box with other text box's as options.. and when pressed closes the popup box.. but I'd like that to then take the value from whichever text box I have selected and add into the original text box. Is this possible? I'm new to wpf so forgive me!

Here is my code so far.

```
 <Grid>

    <StackPanel Margin="0,51,0,-51">
        <TextBox  x:Name="text" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus" Margin="158,0,169,0" Height="24" Text="Select Your Time..." />

        <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="282" Height="300" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=text}">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox  x:Name="text2" Background="White" Margin="10" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus2" Cursor="Arrow" Height="24" Text="1 second" />
                    <TextBox  x:Name="text3" Background="White" Margin="10" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus2" Cursor="Arrow" Height="24" Text="2 second" />
                    <TextBox  x:Name="text4" Background="White" Margin="10" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus2" Cursor="Arrow" Height="24" Text="3 second" />
                    <TextBox  x:Name="text5" Background="White" Margin="10" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus2" Cursor="Arrow" Height="24" Text="4 second" />
                    <TextBox  x:Name="text6" Background="White" Margin="10" GotKeyboardFocus="text_GotKeyboardFocus2" Cursor="Arrow" Height="24" Text="5 second" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>

    </StackPanel>




</Grid>




 private void text_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void text_GotKeyboardFocus2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your point.
Just add `text.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;` to your second event handler as follows :

```
private void text_GotKeyboardFocus2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     popup.IsOpen = false;
     text.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Get value from one textbox to another in xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox1"/>

<TextBox Name="txtBox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBox1, Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Get value from one textbox to another XAML

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox1"/>

<TextBox Name="txtBox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBox1, Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```